# Docker volumes persistence after COPY

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a docker image where I use embedded derby persistence like this :

```
COPY BatchDB /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/BatchDB
COPY derby /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/derby
```

The folder BatchDB has some runtime files that are also copied at image build time.

I want to use docker volumes to persist the `/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/BatchDB` directory, but when running the container if I attach a docker volume created externally by `docker volume create --name dataVolume`, the container does not have any files inside the BatchDB folder.

Is there any way when I mount a volume, I still have the files stored at build-time ?

Comment: Mounted volume has precedence so you won't see the original files over there. You can however build a separate image, `COPY BatchDB /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/BatchDB`, and `VOLUME /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/BatchDB`. Then use the volume with `--volumes_from`

Comment: can you try `ONBUILD` option in Dockerfie?

Comment: I know it works with --volumes-from, but I just wanted to know if it would work with the `docker volume` api.

Comment: I don't know if ONBUILD would work. I thought it's just executed when you build a new image with my image as a base image

Comment: Are you sure that after create volume and container without volume overwritting, your data aren't in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/dataVolume/_data`?
Let me recommend you docker-compose and named volumes (version 3+) instead volumes_from, deprecated after version 2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to prevent other possible errors due to this question is quite old, is important to know that for recent versions, `volumes-from` is deprecated.

So, I'll recommend you to use a named volume, but although your data are stored with COPY in built-time, data in volume are accessible for other containers when you run the service. 
I.e, if you're defining containers with `docker-compose`, data are not in volume directory with `docker-compose` build, but `docker-compose up / run`.

When you do that, you could use it as a volume or even as a bind (attached to host), checking data in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/YOUR_NAMED_VOLUME_NAME/_data`